# Failure to override Element's addEventListener in Firefox

Tags: javascript, events, firefox, prototype, addeventlistener

I'm trying to override the Element object's `addEventListener` method, in a cross-browser manner. The purpose is so that I can load some 3rd party scripts asynchronously, and those scripts call this method prematurely.

I created an HTML file that works perfectly in Chrome, but on Firefox I get this exception:

> "Illegal operation on WrappedNative prototype object"  nsresult: "0x8057000c (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_OP_ON_WN_PROTO)"

If you comment out the lines in the file that change the INSTANCE methods, it works. But I need to do it on the "class type" (i.e. prototype).

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Guypo

Here's the file I created

```
<html><body>
<img id="testImg" src="http://www.blaze.io/wp-content/themes/Blaze/images/header_logoB.png">
<script>
function myLog(msg) { "undefined" != typeof(console) && console.log("Log: " + msg); }
function customListener(type, event, useCapture) {
  // Register the event
  myLog('Registering event');
  this._origListener.apply(this, arguments);
}
// Also tried HTMLImageElement
Element.prototype._origListener = Element.prototype.addEventListener;
Element.prototype.addEventListener = customListener;

var img = document.getElementById("testImg");
// Uncommenting these lines works - but in the real case I can't access these objects
//img._origListener = img.addEventListener;
//img.addEventListener = customListener;
img.addEventListener('load',function() { myLog('load callback'); }, false);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think element prototyping isn't cross-compatible, I would suggest using jQuery or some framework.

Comment: I agree, but I can't modify the 3rd party scripts I'm using, so my only option is to change the JavaScript environment they run in by changing the prototype

Answer (score 6):

Like Marcel says, this has to do with the way host objects are exposed. The problem is that if you override a predefined property of an interface, it doesn't get changed in the interfaces that inherit from it (at least in Firefox).

Although I agree with Marcel's remarks, there *is* in fact a way to do this. You should override the property of the lowest possible interface of the object you want to do this for. In your case this would be the `HTMLImageElement`.

This will do the trick:

```
(function() {
    var _interfaces = [ HTMLDivElement, HTMLImageElement /* ... (add as many as needed) */ ];
    for (var i = 0; i < _interfaces.length; i++) {
        (function(original) {
            _interfaces[i].prototype.addEventListener = function(type, listener, useCapture) {

                // DO SOMETHING HERE

                return original.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        })(_interfaces[i].prototype.addEventListener);
    }
})();
```

Comment: Thanks - I think I tried it before, but am not sure. I'll try it out later and report back.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please use a valid Doctype, preferably one that cast browsers into (Almost) Standards mode (`<!DOCTYPE html>` is fine).
2. `typeof` is an operator, you don't need the parentheses (but it doesn't hurt)
3. Most important: **don't** try to manipulate DOM `Element`'s `prototype`: those are host objects and you can't rely on host objects exposing *any* of the core JavaScript functionality of an object. Worse, there may be a performance penalty and you might break other things. Stay away from that technique. For more information, read [What’s wrong with extending the DOM](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/).

What is it that you want to achieve, that you want your event listeners to be called automatically when using 3rd party scripts?

Comment: I'm trying to run a script that is supposed to run as a <script src=...> tag asynchronously. The goal is to make it non-blocking to the rest of the page. The script finds an element on the page and adds a load event listener to it, and making it async leads to the script running AFTER the element was loaded. So I need to "trap" the registration for the event, so I can check if the element is already loaded, and in that case call the callback right away. All of that is simulated in the example.